# How do I associate my facebook app user with my web app user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have a facebook fbml app and a web application.  I want my web application users to be able to add my facebook app. Seems simple, right?

Currently, I am making the connection by adding a param to the canvas page link in my site.  For example, I have a link that says "add our fbook application" which links to http://apps.facebook.com/our_fbook_application?suid=786432878923

suid is the logged in user's uid on my site.  Adding this to the canvas link params allows me to connect their site uid to their fbook uid on my site.  This way when requests come in from facebook, I can authenticate them based on solely the fbook uid after the connection is made.

This seems like a security issue.  I think an attacker could log into their facebook account and guess user id's by calling http://apps.facebook.com/our_fbook_application?suid=x and when x corresponded to a suid on my site, he would be authenticated to see that user's data.

This connecting of a facebook app user to a website user seems like it should be really common practice, but all I can find these days is facebook connect examples which I am not supporting yet.

Can someone walk me through the steps to connect a facebook app user to my website user?  Major bonus points if someone can do it in Rails with the facebooker gem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

don't pass the suid as a variable.

Instead, on your backend, associate the FB uid with the suid.

When the user accesses the app via website, he/she will have to log in (maybe through fb connect?).

When the user accesses the app via FB, your page should be able to determine the fbuid of the user and map that to the correct suid and log the user into your site.